# Double Type Matrix [n]x[n] transfered to ASSEMBLY

Tags: c, assembly, matrix, memory-address

I would like some help with operation on matrix in assembly language.
My code does Cholesky Decomposition in C and ASM and compare their speed.
I created nested loops already and its working fine, yest i have no idea how to adress properly matrix to access its elements. Matrix is DOUBLE in C and i managed to transer its adress (first element) to assembly.

```
Cholesky_double proc \
         tab_addr:DWORD, \  ; begin adres of matrix
         num_elem:DWORD ; element count in row/column (n of Matrix[n][n])

    LOCAL i:DWORD, k:DWORD, j:DWORD, skoczek:DWORD

;skoczek is for operation count check (ex.should be 13 for 3x3 matrix)

    ; push register on stack
    push edx
    push ecx
    push ebx
    push esi
    push edi

mov k, 0
mov skoczek, 0
for0start:
    inc skoczek 

    mov eax, k
    mov i, eax
    inc i
    ;there should be MATRIX[k][k] = sqrt(MATRIX[k][k])

    mov eax, num_elem
    sub eax, i
    cmp eax, 0
    je for1end

    for1start:
        inc skoczek
            ;MATRIX[i][k]=MATRIX[i][k]/MATRIX[k][k]

    for1koniec:
    inc i
    mov eax, num_elem
    sub eax, i
    cmp eax, 0
    jne for1start
    for1END:

    mov eax, k
    mov j, eax
    inc j

    mov eax, num_elem
    sub eax, j
    cmp eax, 0
    je for2end

    for2start:
        inc skoczek

        mov eax, j
        mov i, eax
        for3start:
            inc skoczek
                    ;MATRIX[i][j] = MATRIX[i][j]-MATRIX[i][k]*MATRIX[j][k]

        for3koniec:
        inc i
        mov eax, num_elem
        sub eax, i
        cmp eax, 0
        jne for3start

    for2koniec:
    inc j
    mov eax, num_elem
    sub eax, j
    cmp eax, 0
    jne for2start
    for2end:

for0koniec:
inc k
mov eax, num_elem
sub eax, k
cmp eax, 0
jne for0start

koniec:
    pop edi
    pop esi
    pop ebx
    pop ecx
    pop edx

    mov eax, skoczek
    ret             
    ; return with operation count in eax

Cholesky_double endp
```

The matrix passed in C with

```
extern "C" int __stdcall Cholesky_double(double* tab_adr, int num_el);
```

I use Visual Studio 2010 and solution with project that create ASSEMBLY library and project with code in C++ that can use assembler functions.

I am not asking for filling code for me, just for a little bit help with correct adressing of matrix to properly access its elemets. If you foresee more problems coming here (like Sqrt in asm i would be pleased with some guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first have to linearize the address:

```
  &matrix[k][i] = matrix + i*sizeof(double) + k*N*sizeof(double);
```

where N is the row width. (Assuming NxN matrix)

That can be loaded with

```
  fld [%eax]        // load to top of stack in FPU (assuming ia-32 system)
  mov %rbx,[%rax];  // vs. load 64-bit register 
  movsd %xmm0, [%rax] // vs. load a double to lower 64-bits of xmm register
```